# RichTextBox as output and TextBox as input on one form, how to select from output while maintaining focus on input?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RichTextBox as output and TextBox as input on the main WinForms form.  I would like to be able to keep focus on the TextBox while highlighting text in the output with the mouse.  That would allow me, as an example, to type something in the input and simultaneously select something in the output with the mouse.

I saw this done in one application which isn't necessarily WinForms based, but it does run on a Windows machine.

How can I do this with WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of

```
    bool selecting;

    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selecting = true;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selecting)
            textBox1.Focus();
        selecting = false;
    }
```

This resets the focus on the TextBox as soon as you finish selecting from the RichTextBox. The problem however is that, as soon as the focus is restored, the selection is cleared.

Comment: In the application I'm referring to, in the output window you would click the mouse, then you can select the text, drag the mouse right or left all the while the input TextBox would still be taking the keybord input, uninterrupted.  Could threads be involved?